# What kind of frame for prescription glasses for a 3 year old?

Tags: pre-schooler, eyes, glasses

I have looked at questions on this site and most of them are trying to get their kids to learn to wear glasses. My question is a pre-cursor of sorts. Just today my 3 and a half year old was diagnosed with astigmatism and the doctor wants him on prescription lens. My question is what kind of frame should I begin searching for ?

History with Sunglasses : Every single time he was bought a sunnies, the first thing he did was to hold the temples (piece that goes over the ear) and pull them apart. After wasting a few sunnies we found the rubber framed ones and there has been no problem. The issue is, none of the optometrists in the city I live in (Australia) stock rubber based frames (most hadn't even heard of such a thing).

Since a frame and lens really cost an arm and leg in Australia, my question is, what kind of a frame should I get for a destructive 3.5 year old for prescription lens ?

Comment: You may want to edit your question slightly to keep it on topic - "which frame" is off topic (asking for specific models), but "what kind of frame" is probably okay (asking for characteristics of frames that are good for children).

Comment: Talk to the opticians about what they offer. This doesn't really seem like a parenting question.

Answer (score 2):

You can always [order the rubber frames online](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0757QZ4VH) and have your optometrist simply put the lenses in.

At the very worst case scenario, you can get your child's prescription, and your own pre-ordered rubber frames, and shop around to find an eyeglass store that will do the work.

I've been doing this for over a decade with my own frames/lenses with very little push-back, though I'm not in Australia so YMMV.